# bootstrap-multiselect select optgroup by default if group doesn't have options

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using bootstrap-multiselect - https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect .
I have problem when I have optgroup which doesn't have options (child). Then those groups are selected by default in multiselect-container, but not in select group. Trying to remove "active" class from all `<li>` elements not working. 
Any help ?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Parent == null)
    {
        <optgroup label="@item.Name" value="@item.Id" id="@item.Id"></optgroup>                        
    }
    else
    {
        <option value="@item.Id" id="@item.Id" class="indent-subProject" data-parent="@item.Parent">@item.Name</option>
    }
}
```

in my script:

```
$('#projects').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    enableClickableOptGroups: true
});

//hide all projects
$('.multiselect-container > li').find('input').each(function () {                       
    $(this).parents().eq(2).addClass("disabled");
    $(this).parents().eq(2).removeClass("active");
});

//show only assigned projects
$('.multiselect-container > li').find('input').each(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < listOfAssignedProjects.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).val() == listOfAssignedProjects[i]) {
            $(this).parents().eq(2).css("display", "block");
            $(this).parents().eq(2).removeClass("disabled");
            $(this).prop("disabled", false);

            $(this).parents().eq(2).removeClass("active");     
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you show your code please?

Comment: yes. As you can see I set all the projects into "select", then hide and disabled all and show only projects assigned to user. That all happened when  ("user").onChange

Comment: There is 3 opened issues about that problem and author describe it as bug, so I don't find solution yet.